# Changing Background and text colour in a Windows console, c++

Tags: c++, windows-console

I have used the following code to change the colour of console . But it highlights the text as well.I don't want my text to be highlighted and want a white background.

```
    using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

//returns the current attributes
WORD GetConsoleTextAttribute (HANDLE hCon)
{
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO con_info;
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hCon, &con_info);

  return con_info.wAttributes;
}

int main (void)
{
  system("color F1");

  HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  const int saved_colors = GetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole);



  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
  cout << "This text should be blue" << endl;
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_colors);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
  cout << "This text should be green" << endl;
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_colors);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make white background yourself

```
WORD whiteBack = BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_INTENSITY;
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | whiteBack);
cout << "This text should be blue" << endl;
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, saved_colors);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | whiteBack);
cout << "This text should be green" << endl;
```